# Django DetailView can't resolve slug for views

Tags: python, django

I have wrote models,views and urls like this

#### models.py

```
class PreventionField(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    verbose_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

#### views.py

```
class PreventionFieldDetailView(DetailView):
    model = PreventionField
    template_name = 'prevention-fields-details.html'

    template_name = "prevention-field-details.html"
    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        return PreventionField.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

#### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', Frontpage.as_view(), name='frontpage'),
    path('fields/<slug>/',PreventionFieldDetailView.as_view(),name='fields')]
```

And what I want is to generate slug urls based on entries in PreventionField model that I can switch between subpages in my website like

http://mywebsite.com/fields/neuro
where neuro slugfield from model,but this return error

#### FieldError at /fields/neuro/

#### Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field. Choices are: id, name , verbose_name

and ok,so I have to switch from 'slug' into 'name' because this is my SlugField in model PreventionField,right? Well, when I change views.py code to

```
            return PreventionField.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['name'])
```

then got following error:

#### KeyError at /fields/neuro/

#### 'name'

and now I've lost it.

I don't understand why DetailView works this way and how I should change it to obtain slug url.

#### PS

I should mention that I didin't have problems when I was using pk instead of slug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got this the wrong way round. The field in your model is called `name`. So:

```
return PreventionField.objects.get(name=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

It would be much better though to just set `slug_field = 'name'` at class level in the view, then you don't need to define `get_object` at all.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work on my code. I am loosing my mind